# C# Как совершить такую замену?

Tags: c#

Вот допустим есть у меня такой текстовик

[image]

хочу сделать программу.

Будет работать примерно так

[image]

название поля windowBg: и справа идет само поле куда вписывается допустим #00ff00
и нужно при нажатии на кнопку на выходе получить текстовик с уже замененным значением, то есть чтоб вместо
windowBg: #bd4b4b;
было windowBg: #00ff00; как сделать такую замену?

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Вы не знаете как прочитать и распарсить текстовый файл? Или как вывести потом необходимое число полей на форме? Или не знаете как сохранить данные в текстовый файл? Это разные задачи. Пока вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Если нужно заменить часть с # то командой прочитай всю строку сделай подстроку с первого появления # и всё

Comment: Суть вопроса не понятна

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, нужно найти в файле значение по ключу, изменить его и перезаписать файл. Тогда вот так:

```
// ключ, по которому будем искать, и значение, на которое будем менять
string key = "windowBg", value = "#00ff00";
// сюда читаем и сохраняем весь файл
List<string> text = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        text.Add(reader.ReadLine());
// ищем нужную нам строку по ключу и меняем в ней значение на новое
for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
{
    if (text[i].Split(':')[0] == key)
    {
        text[i] = string.Format("{0}: {1};", key, value);
        break;
    }
}
// записываем файл с изменениями
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
    foreach (string line in text)
        writer.WriteLine(line);
```

Писал в браузере и не проверял, так что извините за ошибки, если будут.